# Where to find logs for OpenVPN launched via KDE "Connections" on OpenSUSE?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, kde, opensuse

On OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, in the KDE environment, I used KDE's NetworkManager (the "Connections" System Settings Module) to set up an OpenVPN connection.

When I connect to it, there are no error messages, but it does not behave as I would expect.

Where can I find logs that are relevant to diagnosing an OpenVPN connection that is created and initiated through KDE on OpenSUSE Tubleweed?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you can find those in either */var/log* (either within *syslog* or in a file called *openvpn.log*) or */etc/openvpn*, but you should read your configuration file, *something.conf*, for custom definitions:

```
log /path/to/some/file
log-append /path/to/some/other/file
```

Comment: `syslog` nor `openvpn.log` exist in `/var/log`. There is a readme file in `/var/log` that explains how most logs will be found in the systemd journal instead, but the systemd journal does not contain any lines that contain "openvpn".

The configuration generated and used by the NetworkManager is not the standard openvpn format, so `log path` cannot be appended to it.

Your answer may be correct on another distribution or with a manual OpenVPN configuration, but on OpenSUSE with the KDE Connections interface, it is not.